# How to stop AWS SES Spamming my gmail email?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, gmail, gmail-api

Gmail gets flooded with spam emails from AWS Ses

After my spam email folder gets full the gmail is not getting any more emails. How can I report to AWS Ses not to send me an email from a specific AWS Ses Account.

Here is the details. I have contacted the company who is sending the emails. They are unable to solve the issue. ( In 3 years cant cope with change ).

I was once a permitted receiver but not anymore. Help would be appreciated.

[image]

> Delivered-To: rifaterdemsahin@gmail.com Received: by 10.100.151.140
>   with SMTP id q12csp736984pja;
>           Thu, 22 Jun 2017 18:55:26 -0700 (PDT) X-Received: by 10.200.47.87 with SMTP id k23mr6662116qta.11.1498182926606;
>           Thu, 22 Jun 2017 18:55:26 -0700 (PDT) ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1498182926; cv=none;
>           d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
>           b=VjPlf2DSOO/X+jFewPovx0GPtS81NriE988G1yhFs0sWUAULrnp31pIDjiI3v/MC2h
>            VOJDD6IkKpp+gsU4gYLo8BRoS71ZiHtB6O7Yk1z5Nc7QKxk+FjBuGK75Y8qM3dObxCKU
>            FpZ3vwZrmwHbL8etRznU/DwfcN5f60GP45eINzKe7QYS+HOquiISKfFI6Kjac5/GvHqu
>            fRL2zdFHu5E2aIXGUMUK4EdVsFjMQUsJUqBJC0OSoqLesyLdoyqV4oTAunH8BwYKWEY4
>            /JTNP2zR6+6wucgfEVVPUQ5W6ocKVWPlJnHDw+vP1y6JkKMNaNj9mYl0LORMKHU71ptN
>            f8Ig== ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
>           h=feedback-id:date:message-id:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version
>            :subject:to:from:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
>           bh=Y7pVjQ5emAE4pdcubLwi7473vY3OWUVV5NusExrVNc8=;
>           b=DlgSuorHXVeVtWhKM/csFcSeADLzJCLSuzCwZEsHVT7XLtmwSQERCwlIDHyabl8Ffa
>            NNXx8CCYYfrAu0mbg3vGnAvG8SmusEwfBe0cAaa7D1bGf2fM/hGJzsQX21e3rbyQzvnu
>            GSTZjwpW48sFkWzN863wLai5Z2Ne+eR/7lyzfEO/mIIJL0f3uvVmV32kFYMWHxYz0x8/
>            r8GpiLqfD6nxMqvpxn04a/KYgo97/TxyB9AFaKEN08ih1d7+qLE5isq+BJI2NjCJLHnW
>            vqlM1ideeygoN20cgTaz6ZQpYOQAsO0SIZQkoOtkT/6eb0DNCEa1RO45AmMgC9ZJ4rkc
>            PYKQ== ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
>          dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.b=WNeDQXRK;
>          spf=pass (google.com: domain of 0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@amazonses.com
>   designates 54.240.9.109 as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mailfrom=0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@amazonses.com
>   Return-Path:
>   <0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@amazonses.com>
>   Received: from a9-109.smtp-out.amazonses.com
>   (a9-109.smtp-out.amazonses.com. [54.240.9.109])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h186si1190862qkc.200.2017.06.22.18.55.26
>           for 
>           (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
>           Thu, 22 Jun 2017 18:55:26 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of
>   0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@amazonses.com
>   designates 54.240.9.109 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.9.109;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.b=WNeDQXRK;
>          spf=pass (google.com: domain of 0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@amazonses.com
>   designates 54.240.9.109 as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mailfrom=0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@amazonses.com
>   DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
>   s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono; d=amazonses.com; t=1498182926;
>   h=From:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID;
>   bh=VCZKg8hFUb63lOKDitSw+wHccKQ7iJdOqT+3v5T9kMM=;
>   b=WNeDQXRKVjREfsyiCHuwazQD7AXWRfZc3UcrwH1AghtaCnavxJ6CBSLTUsIqc5GF
>   m6/uRCDItr6crWjplYgl14Dq2mbGHMFtB+vZHh0PPNmO4n3+/8PevleQbEYInRWmlec
>   ZbFX57QHhrNXtEyUc4qaM3ZtjpcwjaPzOXe2liB8= From: No-Reply
>    To: rifaterdemsahin@gmail.com Subject:
>   Performance Warning(3x) IP: 192.168.30.40 Method:
>   Broadage.Common.Tools.Email MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Message-ID:
>   <0100015cd2a93eb9-85164c9c-6cfb-46ec-a985-02909a4b6b0c-000000@email.amazonses.com>
>   Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 01:55:26 +0000 X-SES-Outgoing:
>   2017.06.23-54.240.9.109 Feedback-ID: 1.us-east-1.SIJlVA2xTbAVdBXctlUaxBDeEU1mquOgueuof7Nldbc=:AmazonSES
>
> **Performans Uyar=C4=B1s=C4=B1**
> **Mak= ine Ip** =3D>  192.168.30.40
> **Uygulama Ad=C4=B1 =3D>  
> **Method Name** =3D>  Broadage.Common= .Tools.Email
> =C4=B0stenilen Performans S=C3=BCresi =3D>
>   250 ms elapsed time
>
> Harcanan S=C3=BCre**= 
>   =3D> 786.708 ms elapsed time

Comment: I am still getting the emails even thoug i reported to AWS ses services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As pointed by Jordan Stewart, configure your filter to delete messages, but don't mark them as spam.

2) As complaint directly to the company did not work, I suggest complaining to AWS. See here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/report-aws-abuse/
They seem to take abuse (or misuse) of their platform quite seriously. So, I would expect the company will be forced to either fix the issue or be disconnected from SES service.

Comment: Seva complaint answer could be it. Let me try and let you know

Comment: that is the link I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to automatically delete the emails in the gmail, through setting up a filter. I think this page explains how to setup the filter: https://www.businessinsider.com.au/automatically-delete-unwanted-gmail-2014-1

I don't think you can interact with their setup of AWS SES. If you were able to it would be a security vulnerability of SES.

It could be possible to setup a gmail custom script that could delete the emails, but in affect it would be doing the same thing as the filter. Except the filter is easier.

I think the business sending unwanted information is probably against an anti-spam act. So what they are doing is probably illegal, or at least probably negligent.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is i already delete and mark them as spam. Still gmail gets overloaded via receiving so many. Over 10k a day

Comment: Gmail should reject the emails aws ses should stop that. I could not find anyone to connect at aws ses

Comment: Do you delete them automatically, or are the emails just moved to junk? I believe deleting them automatically, and moving them to junk automatically are slightly different. I think if you delete them your junk won't become full.

Comment: 10k a day is a lot of emails.

Comment: Reported this to AWS today one more time. And got this : An Amazon Web Services Business Representative will contact you in the next 72 hours.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of AWS, this is an error that needs to be fixed from the company that is sending these emails. There is SES probation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/e-faq-sp.html). I would try emailing ses-enforcement@amazon.com and see if they can help you.